# Negative binomial maximum likelihood

Tags: probability, statistics

The pdf of a negative binomial is

$$θ(X=x)= \left( \begin{array}{c}
x+j-1  \\
x  \end{array} \right)(1-θ)^xθ^j,$$

How would I create the likelihood of this function in order to maximize θ?And how does the likelihood change if there is n observations vs. 1 observation?

So far, I have that the likelihood is

∏ (j + x − 1 C x)*θ^j*(1-θ)^x

which is simplified to (through the derivative of the log-likelihood)

=jn*lnθ+∑X*ln(1-θ)

Meaning that jn/θ=∑X/1-θ

I solved for theta and have:

θ-hat= jn/(jn+∑x)

Is there something wrong? If so, where?

---

Something extra:

(The alternative pdf is $$P(X=x|j,θ)= \binom{x-1}{j-1}θ^{j}(1-θ)^{x-j}$$

would it yield the same likelihood?)

Comment: $\theta$ should be $p$ on RHS?

Comment: yes, I modified it to be consistent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation

Comment: I'm not quite sure why the gamma function is used

Comment: @risdel Because in the general case, the parameter $j$ is not required to be a natural number; however, if it is, then the gamma function reduces to a factorial.

Comment: I solved for θ and can't see why my answer doesn't match the wiki's? How come they have a summation on the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the PDF

$$P(X = x|j, \theta)
= {x + j - 1 \choose x}\theta^j(1-\theta)^{x},$$
for $x = 0, 1, \dots$, where $x$ is the number of
failures observed before seeing the $j$th success
and $\theta$ is the probability of success on any
one trial. I am being fussy about writing everything
out in full, because (as you will see) every detail
is important here.

With data $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n,$
you set the partial derivative of the loglikelihood 
function equal to $0$ to find the estimator

$$\hat \theta = \frac{jn}{jn + T},$$
where $T = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i,$ which is the total number
of failures seen while waiting for $nj$ successes.

If I read the notes on your derivation correctly, I think
you did it correctly.

Furthermore, this estimator of $\theta$ makes sense,
because the numerator is the number of successes observed
and the denominator is the total number of trials
performed.

---

Now to try to clear up some of your additional questions
in the original post and arising from Comments.

(1) What changes if $n = 1$? There is no product sign
in the likelihood and so summation sign in the equation to
solve for the estimator. The estimator becomes 
$\hat \theta = j/(j + x).$ Again the estimator is the
ratio of the number $j$ of successes to the total number
of trials until those $j$ successes are observed.

2) If you change to the alternative PDF, the estimator
will still be the number $nj$ of success divided by the total
number of trials necessary to to observe them. However, the
equation will not look the same, because this is the PDF
of a different random variable. Now $X$ is defined as the
total number of $trials$ (not $failures$) until $nj$
successes are seen. This random variable takes values
$x = j,\, j+1,\, j+2,\, \dots.$

3) Your answer is not the same as the one in Wikipedia
because the random variable there counts the number of
$successes$ until (in your notation) $nj$ failures are
observed. (I frequently refer questioners to Wikipedia,
but not always. Sometimes is is not at the right level,
has confusing notation, or formulates an issue in
a different way than in the problem posted. Sometimes Wikipedia
is helpful, sometimes not; here I think not.)

Please check everything here. I am not the world's
best proofreader. And leave a Comment for me if there
are unresolved issues about your question. I, or
someone else, will try to help.